# Add Router to Angular 9 project

Tags: angular-cli, angular9

I am trying to add Router to a project that when was created didn't not say yes to Router.
Here is the command I am running:

```
npm install -g @angular/router
```

And here the project config and the result of the command:

```
Angular CLI: 9.1.1
Node: 10.15.1
OS: win32 x64

Angular: 9.1.2
... common, compiler, compiler-cli, core
Ivy Workspace: Yes

Package                             Version
-------------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect           0.901.1
@angular-devkit/build-angular       0.901.1
@angular-devkit/build-ng-packagr    0.901.1
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer     0.901.1
@angular-devkit/build-webpack       0.901.1
@angular-devkit/core                9.1.1
@angular-devkit/schematics          9.1.1
@angular/animations                 9.0.7
@angular/cdk                        9.2.1
@angular/cli                        9.1.1
@angular/flex-layout                9.0.0-beta.29
@angular/forms                      9.0.7
@angular/language-service           9.0.7
@angular/material                   9.2.1
@angular/platform-browser           9.0.7
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic   9.0.7
@angular/router                     9.0.7
@ngtools/webpack                    9.1.1
@schematics/angular                 9.1.1
@schematics/update                  0.901.1
ng-packagr                          9.1.1
rxjs                                6.5.5
typescript                          3.7.5
webpack                             4.42.0

PS D:\PrismNewUI\PrismWebUIUX> npm install -g @angular/router
npm WARN @angular/router@9.1.3 requires a peer of @angular/core@9.1.3 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @angular/router@9.1.3 requires a peer of @angular/common@9.1.3 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @angular/router@9.1.3 requires a peer of @angular/platform-browser@9.1.3 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @angular/router@9.1.3 requires a peer of rxjs@^6.5.3 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @angular/router@9.1.3 requires a peer of tslib@^1.10.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

+ @angular/router@9.1.3
updated 1 package in 0.482s
```

Seems to me the current router version is higher than my project.

AS I understand the router is not getting installed. What do I  do in this case?

Thanks

Without Global flag:

```
PS D:\PrismNewUI\PrismWebUIUX> npm install @angular/router
npm WARN @angular-devkit/build-ng-packagr@0.901.1 requires a peer of tsickle@~0.37.1 || ~0.38.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @angular/animations@9.0.7 requires a peer of @angular/core@9.0.7 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @angular/forms@9.0.7 requires a peer of @angular/core@9.0.7 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @angular/forms@9.0.7 requires a peer of @angular/common@9.0.7 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @angular/platform-browser@9.0.7 requires a peer of @angular/core@9.0.7 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @angular/platform-browser@9.0.7 requires a peer of @angular/common@9.0.7 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@9.0.7 requires a peer of @angular/core@9.0.7 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@9.0.7 requires a peer of @angular/common@9.0.7 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@9.0.7 requires a peer of @angular/compiler@9.0.7 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @rollup/plugin-json@4.0.2 requires a peer of rollup@^1.20.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN sass-loader@8.0.2 requires a peer of node-sass@^4.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN sass-loader@8.0.2 requires a peer of fibers@>= 3.1.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN webpack-subresource-integrity@1.4.0 requires a peer of html-webpack-plugin@^2.21.0 || ~3 || >=4.0.0-alpha.2 <5 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @angular/router@9.0.7 requires a peer of @angular/core@9.0.7 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @angular/router@9.0.7 requires a peer of @angular/common@9.0.7 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.1.2 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.1.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.12 (node_modules\webpack-dev-server\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.12: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.12 (node_modules\watchpack\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.12: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

+ @angular/router@9.0.7
updated 1 package and audited 17382 packages in 11.929s
found 2 low severity vulnerabilities
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
```

Answer (score 0):

`npm install -g @angular/router` installs the router globally on your computer. Basically on Windows the globally installed npm dependencies can be found on `%AppData%/npm` path. If the globally installed npm packages have command line interface (like `angular-cli`) the commands will be accessible directly from the shell.

If you want to install the router in a local project you can add the needed version "by hand" to the `package.json` in the `dependencies` JSON entry and call `npm install` from the path, where the `package.json` can be found. The newly added dependency will be downloaded in the `node_modules` of the project.

Or if you don't want to add it "by hand" to the `package.json` you can call `npm install @angular/router@<wishedversion>` on the path, where the `package.json` of the project is. This way the router will be installed in the `node_modules` and the `package.json` will be updated. (Of course `<wishedversion>` should be the version, which you need.)

However I see above in the dependencies the `@angular/router: 9.0.7`. This means, that it is already in the `package.json` so only an `npm install` call is needed from the path of the `package.json` to install it in the local `node_modules`.

Comment: @angular/router@<wishedversion>. I tried several versions, none worked. Which one do I need based on the provided configuration?

Comment: But why do you need the router globally installed on the computer?

Comment: I am not even thinking about that. All I want is to add Router to the project.

Comment: The `npm install -g @angular/router` command contains the `-g` parameter, which means it is installed globally on your computer.

Comment: Without -g parameter it produces different result. I am posting it now.

Comment: It seems to be fine `@angular/router@9.0.7` was installed sucessfully. However there are a lot of peer depedencies that seem to be missing.

Comment: Router 9.0.7 was there before. Shouldn't be router also shown here: Angular: 9.1.2
... common, compiler, compiler-cli, core
Ivy Workspace: Yes